# Jenkin build fails after maven dependencies upgrade

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, intellij-idea

Recently, I was working on upgrading the dependencies of one of my team's projects. After changes, project built successfully locally on my laptop. But the same code change threw compilation error on Jenkins.

The errors I am encountering is related to `class file for xxx.xxx.xxx. not found` in powermockito package. Attaching some relevant pieces of code for reference.

Pervious pom version used:

```
... some lines above it ...   

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!--dropwizard versions-->
    <dropwizard.version>1.3.5</dropwizard.version>
    <dropwizard.swagger.version>1.0.0-2-auth-SNAPSHOT</dropwizard.swagger.version>
    <dropwizard.bundle.version>1.3.5-1</dropwizard.bundle.version>
    <dropwizard.requestinfo>1.3.5-3</dropwizard.requestinfo>
    <dropwizard.rosey.data.provider.version>1.3.5-3</dropwizard.rosey.data.provider.version>
    <dropwizard.service.discovery>1.3.5-0</dropwizard.service.discovery>
    <dropwizard.rmq.actor.version>1.2.2-1</dropwizard.rmq.actor.version>
    <dropwizard.riemann.version>1.3.5-4</dropwizard.riemann.version>

    <!--hystrix versions-->
    <hystrix.dropwizard.version>0.4</hystrix.dropwizard.version>
    <hystrix.configurator.version>0.0.6</hystrix.configurator.version>
    <hystrix.version>1.5.3</hystrix.version>
    <hystrix.wrapper.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</hystrix.wrapper.version>

    <!--internal clients-->
    <user-service-model.version>1.7.91</user-service-model.version>
    <kratos.version>0.8.2-SNAPSHOT</kratos.version>
    <rosey.dropwizard.config>1.14</rosey.dropwizard.config>

    <!--others-->
    <mysql.driver.version>5.1.38</mysql.driver.version>
    <okhttp3.version>3.4.1</okhttp3.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <powemock.version>1.7.3</powemock.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.191</h2.version>
    <square.okhttp.version>3.4.1</square.okhttp.version>
    <rmq.version>4.1.0</rmq.version>
    <zookeeper.version>3.4.13</zookeeper.version>
    <curator.version>4.0.1</curator.version>
</properties>

... some lines below it ...
```

Current pom version used:

```
... some lines above it ...

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!--dropwizard versions-->
    <dropwizard.version>1.3.12</dropwizard.version>
    <dropwizard.swagger.version>1.3.7-1</dropwizard.swagger.version>
    <dropwizard.bundle.version>1.3.5-1</dropwizard.bundle.version>
    <dropwizard.requestinfo>1.3.5-8</dropwizard.requestinfo>
    <dropwizard.rosey.data.provider.version>1.3.5-6</dropwizard.rosey.data.provider.version>
    <dropwizard.service.discovery>1.3.12-3</dropwizard.service.discovery>
    <dropwizard.rmq.actor.version>1.3.12-1</dropwizard.rmq.actor.version>
    <dropwizard.db.sharding.bundle.version>1.3.12-3</dropwizard.db.sharding.bundle.version>
    <dropwizard.riemann.version>1.3.12-1</dropwizard.riemann.version>

    <!--hystrix versions-->
    <hystrix.dropwizard.version>0.4</hystrix.dropwizard.version>
    <hystrix.configurator.version>0.0.6</hystrix.configurator.version>
    <hystrix.version>1.5.3</hystrix.version>

    <!--internal clients-->
    <user-service-model.version>1.7.96-STAGE-SNAPSHOT</user-service-model.version>
    <kratos.version>0.9.6</kratos.version>
    <rosey.dropwizard.config>1.15</rosey.dropwizard.config>

    <!-- storage -->
    <aerospike.version>3.3.0</aerospike.version>
    <mock.aerospike.version>0.0.4</mock.aerospike.version>

    <!--others-->
    <okhttp3.version>3.4.1</okhttp3.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <powemock.version>1.7.3</powemock.version>
    <guava.version>28.0-jre</guava.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.199</h2.version>
    <rmq.version>5.7.2</rmq.version>
    <zookeeper.version>3.4.13</zookeeper.version>
    <curator.version>4.2.0</curator.version>
    <sentinel.model.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</sentinel.model.version>
</properties>

... some lines below it ...
```

Shortend error logs:

```
... some code above it ...  

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/resources/MerchantResourceTest.java:[19,1] cannot access org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier
  class file for org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier not found
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/resources/VPAResourceTest.java:[29,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/resources/VPAResourceTest.java:[30,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/services/PrimerServiceTest.java:[28,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/services/PrimerServiceTest.java:[29,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/resources/AddressResourceTest.java:[22,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/resources/AddressResourceTest.java:[23,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/services/WalletServiceTest.java:[27,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/services/WalletServiceTest.java:[28,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/resources/MerchantResourceTest.java:[24,25] cannot access org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner
  class file for org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner not found
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/resources/VPAResourceTest.java:[37,25] incompatible types: java.lang.Class<org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends org.junit.runner.Runner>
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/resources/BaseResourceTest.java:[26,19] package org.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/resources/BaseResourceTest.java:[30,26] package org.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/src/test/java/com/xxxxxxx/userservice/resources/BaseResourceTest.java:[30,1] static import only from classes and interfaces

... some code below it ...
```

**Experiment I did**: When I removed the test scope from the powermockito dependency, everything worked like a charm.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powemock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>          <- This line
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powemock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>          <- This line
    </dependency>
```

Pasting mockito's maven dependency tree below

```
... some line above it ...

[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.7.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.7.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.7.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.7.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.7.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.7.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.7.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test

... some lines below it ...
```

Maven command which is executing on Jenkins, ***below sample is taken from console log:***

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/UserService_Develop/workspace/pom.xml -U clean package cobertura:cobertura docker:build docker:push -Pdocker -Dproject.version=1.8.23-SNAPSHOT -Dbuild.number=1501 -Dbuild.revision=9d8d00591c23b061b07e1a08c00ff024db8ba318 -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DskipTests -DargLine=-Xmx512m
```

Ideally, it should not have happened. I googled for few days found this blog [Why your tests may pass locally but fail in Jenkins](https://objectpartners.com/2018/09/18/why-your-tests-may-pass-locally-but-fail-in-jenkins/). Unfortunately, nothing seems to work for me. Need some assitance here. Thanks!

Comment: What Maven command is the Jenkins build running?

Comment: Hi @user944849, I have added the maven command which is building the project. Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: What's your version of mockito ? Also, I found something similar on their github https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/818

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel, I have added the dependency tree on the question.

Comment: One of the reasons for such kind of issue is conflicting classes, see the source library of the conflicting class and see from all that library is getting included, Just a suggestion.

Comment: Does it work if you delete your local `~/.m2/repository`? setings.xml is the same? Environment variables are similar?

Comment: Please show us your project structure.

Comment: Can you please paste the complete pom.xml

Answer (score 4):

Your experiment shows that the dependency tree is not the problem. What is the problem is the scope of the dependency. The test scope only adds the dependency to the classpath for test compilation and test execution.

What may go wrong here is that your test classes are actually compiled in the compile phase, not the test-compile phase. A test you can do to check this is to leave the scope as `test` and try to build the project with `mvn compile`, which should NOT build the test sources if everything is configured correctly.

Other than that, is it hard to guess what exactly your are doing and where it could go wrong without seeing the complete pom.xml, but I hope this gives you a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an hypothesis on why code compiled when you removed the `test` scope:

In terms of scope, [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) suggests the following:

> **compile**
>
> This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile
>   dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project.
>   Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.
>
> **test**
>
> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal
>   use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation
>   and execution phases. This scope is not transitive.

Now, this may mean that the `classpath` for scope `test` compilation may potentially differ from the `classpath` for scope `compile`

When you removed the test scope, the mockito jars were found as the default scope is `compile`